# how to get refresh token in '@google-cloud/express-oauth2-handlers'

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

It seems Google's official package Oauth `express-oauth2-handlers` hides too much information. On e important piece is how do we get refresh token or where is the refresh token stored?

Here is how I use it:

> const auth = Auth('datastore', requiredScopes, 'email', true);

Then auth succeeds, the access token in stored in `datastore`. But refresh token is not there. So I am curious where to retrieve it when the current access token expired.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at the source code and it seems that the refresh token is stored inside the JSON encoded and encrypted stored token.

You can take a look yourself [on github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/express-oauth2-handlers/blob/master/tokenStorage.js#L63).

If the token is expired (or close to expiration date) the library makes a call to refresh the access token providing the refresh token stored in the oauth2credentials or from the token if the former doesn't exists.

<sup>**Note:** I have never used this library, maybe it's worth to wait for somebody with a deeper knowledge about the topic to give a more detailed answer.</sup>